# Find, print, and remove all but one of the repeated lines PYTHON

Tags: python, extract, repeat, lines

I have a large text file with lines looking like:

```
data123||data456
data146||data269
data123||data456
data697||data983
data123||data456
```

I want to find repeated lines such as data123||data456 in the above example, print those lines, and then delete all but one copy of the line in the file. I want to be able to extract LINES that are exactly the same.

So far, I have the following code, but it seems to print all repeated "data###" if it happens to show up more than once, regardless of the other 'data###' that it is paired off with it. In other words, I want to extract entire LINES that repeat verbatim, and not just separate 'data####'.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    seen = set ()
    for line in f:
            line_lower =line.lower()
            if line_lower in seen:
                print (line)
            else:
                seen.add(line_lower)
```

Comment: Do you actually want to keep the duplicates in a separate list (or, in your case, printing it)?

Comment: it would be great if I could keep a record of the duplicated lines by printing it or saving it in a separate file

Comment: see answer. it allows to keep in separate lists the unique and the duplicate records. but the check is exact and case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

1. get file lines

   ```
   lines = open("file.txt").readlines()
   ```
2. get a set based on those lines. duplicates are not included in the set

   ```
   ulines = set(lines)
   ```
3. for each line in the set, we remove one instance of that line from the original list

   ```
   for line in ulines:
       #we know the line will exist in the list, because it exists in the set
       lines.remove(line)
   ```
4. finally, the set contains non-duplicates, and the list contains duplicated (non-iterated by the set) instances. we can get "which lines were duplicated" by doing

   ```
   duplicated = set(lines)

   print duplicated
   print ulines
   ```

see http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html << list.remove(x), and "5.4 sets"

Comment: `lines.remove` will only remove one instance from the list. Ths question appears to say that the duplicate should only be printed a single time (even if the line appears in the file 3 times).

Comment: so, he could keep the set. my answer lets you keep both lists

Comment: But that set contains all unique lines, regardless of whether they are duplicates. What the questioner probably wants is `set(lines)` (for your final values of `lines`).

Comment: i tried the code. It seems to remove the duplicate only once. So if there were 4 repeats of the same line, only one repeat was removed, leaving the three.

Comment: @user2743902 See my comment above. You just need to use `set(lines)` of the final value of `lines`.

Comment: aaaah I understood :D. sorry - i did not sleep well today xD. answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

If your file isn't huge, here is an easy way to to it:

```
lines = [line.lower() for line in open("file.txt")]
unique = set(lines)
duplicates = set([line for line in unique if lines.count(line) > 1])
```

`duplicates` will contain a single instance of each value of `unique` that appears more than once in the file.

Answer (score -1):

You have the if statement reversed. You only want to print lines you haven't seen before, right? So shouldn't it be

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    seen = set ()
    for line in f:
        line_lower = line.lower()
        if line_lower not in seen:
            print (line)
            seen.add(line_lower)
```

Comment: this seems to work but is there any way I can print the duplicated lines that were removed? i want to be able to keep a record of them.